# C++, recursive correct answer but not being returned correctly

Tags: c++, recursion, return, garbage

Ok, so heres my simple program for calculating Greatest common divisor. It is returning a garbage value everytime the same as 46332964. Ive thought over my head for an hour but cant seem to understand the problem. After research, i also included the prototype but still no luck. It works until it returns. Please copy the code and run it and please help me.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int calculate_gcd(int aa, int bb, int rem, int g);

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    int rem = -1;
    int gcd=0;

    cout << "Number 1: "; //taking inputs
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Number 2: ";
    cin >> b;

    if (a < b) //swapping if number greater than the number according to the code
    {
       a = a + b;
       b = a - b;
       a = a - b;
    }

    gcd = calculate_gcd(a, b, rem, gcd);

    if (a <= 0 || b <= 0)
    {
       rem = 0;
       cout <<"GCD doesnot exists\n";
    } //just in case of zeros
    else
        cout << "\nthe GCD of "<<a <<" and "<<b <<" is "<<gcd <<"\n\n"; //the main answer

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int calculate_gcd(int aa, int bb, int rem, int g)
{
    if (rem != 0)
    {
       if (aa%bb == 0)
        {
           rem = 0;
           g = bb;
           printf("**GCD is %d\n", g);
        }
        else {
             rem = aa % bb;
             aa = bb;
             bb = rem;
        }
        calculate_gcd(aa, bb, rem, g);
    }
    else {
         printf("**here also GCD is correct as %d \n", g);
         return g; //returning 
         }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a  return.  You should use `return calculate_gcd(aa, bb, rem, g);` instead of just recursing.

You can catch this with clang using `-Wreturn-type`.  Other compilers probably also have a warning for this.

Comment: Thank you. seems to work. I changed the recursing line to "return calculate_gcd(aa, bb, rem, g);"
also let return g; stay.
but why? seems very hard to think about this :(

Comment: the type of `calculate_gcd` is `int (int aa, int bb, int rem, int g)`.  This means that, given `aa`, `bb`, `rem`, and `g`, you *promise* to return an `int`.  If your function decides to recurse, it calls a *new copy* of that function.  It doesn't get you out of the promise to return an integer.  In fact, not returning an integer when you say you're going to results in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The function head

```
int calculate_gcd(int aa, int bb, int rem, int g)
```

specifies that `g` is **passed by value**.

That means that in a call, the specified value is copied to this function invocation’s local `g`. Changes to that local `g` have no effect on the calling site.

Instead you should **`return`** the function result, and then you don’t need the `g` argument:

```
int calculate_gcd(int aa, int bb, int rem)
```

Closer analysis will show you that you do not really need the `rem` argument either, so:

```
int calculate_gcd(int aa, int bb)
```

---

In passing, as a beginner you will benefit greatly from using C++ *iostreams*, like `cout`, instead of low level C i/o functions like `printf`. That’s because `printf` and family do not perform any type checking, so it’s very easy to get wrong.

Also, although this may sound like just balderdash, you will benefit much by lining things up properly vertically, i.e. by using 100% consistent *indentation*. Happily there are free tools that help with this. If your favorite IDE or editor doesn’t support automatic source code formatting, then check out the free AStyle program.

Comment: Thanks, i probably understand this. I will try this out tomorrow because of bed time here. Then choose a correct answer